# Javascript if statement, function is not called

Tags: javascript, if-statement, image-preloader, loadimage

I found a very nice code here to preload images into application. Which works great.

```
// PRELOAD IMAGES
var  images = {};
function loadImages(sources, callback) {

  var loadedImages = 0;
  var numImages = 0;
  // get num of sources
  for(var src in sources) {
    numImages++;
  }
  for(var src in sources) {
    images[src] = new Image();
    images[src].onload = function() {
      if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
        callback(images);
      }
    };
    images[src].src = sources[src];
  }
}


var sources;
sources = {

  img1: "....../img1.png",
  img2: "....../img2.png",

};
```

When loadImages() called it works just fine.

```
loadImages(sources, function(images) {
    ctxLogo.drawImage(images.img1, 0, 0, 10, 10);

  });
```

But when i try to call loadImages() from if statement inside for loop, for whatever reasons the function is not called. 
I am pulling image names from the array.
Everything else works as intented i.e. iteration, conditions, etc. Code is below:

```
 loadImages(sources, function (images) {
 for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {

  if (data[j].FlImg === 'img2') {

    alert (j) // just to be sure it gets here, it does.



      alert(j +'-this line is not')

      ctxGameBoard.drawImage(images.img2, 0, 0, 100, 100);
}
});
```

I ran it locally.
Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

**Solved.**  My problem was that object variable were not declared within if block. once I changed the code to run loop and condition inside loadImages function. Everything works as intended. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: is the second block of code outside of the loadImages function? how is your images parameter being set? It looks like you're passing null and therefore your loadImages function will error out because images is null or undefined.

Comment: What "if statement inside for loop"? Please show your complete code.

Comment: Yes, make sure the callback in the top function is being called.

Comment: what about `sources`? Is it defined before the `for-in` loop?

Comment: Well, there can be many reasons that the function is not called, the simplest one being that not all images were loaded (at least one errored out?). Is any exception thrown, are any errors shown in your browser developer tools? What debugging have you done, how many `onload` callbacks are invoked?

Comment: add `console.log(sources);` between `function loadImages(sources, callback) {` and  `var loadedImages = 0;`; what do you get?

Comment: You're missing a few semicolons...

Comment: @Sander that (usually) doesn't matter; JS has automatic semi-colon insertion

Answer (score 0):

You were accessing `images` like an object, in your second `for/in` loop:

```
images[src] = new Image();
```

But you haven't declare the variable yet. You may find **ReferenceError** in your DevTools.

Comment: images was declared. i didn't copy that part. Updated code is showing.

Answer (score 0):

First,you can use this code to get number of sources instead:

```
var numImages = sources.length;
```

Second,your object variable 'images' is undefined;

Third,your numImages is already getter than loadedImages,so the if statement will be called only once thta is the last.

Comment: I defined 'images'. That parts of the code wasn't copied. It's corrected. Still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Solved. My problem was that object variable were not declared within if block. once I changed the code to run loop and condition inside loadImages function. Everything works as intended. Thanks for pointing it out.